# making a Vec<Child> containing reference to Parent struct?

Tags: rust, lifetime, self, borrow-checker, mutable

Im new to Rust, and i'm having this problem where I need to keep a Vec of Child in the Parent struct, and each child needs to be able to use the Parent functions, so with some research I ended up with this, however , its not really working, as I always end up with the same error:

> Cannot borrow `self.children` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference `self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable)*

This is a simplified version of my real code, but it has the same problem. I need to do the add_child from within Parent, because in the real code it has more functionality that depends on the Parent that helps create the Child.

```
struct Parent<'a> {
    children: Vec<Child<'a>>,
}

impl<'b> Parent<'b> {
    fn add_child(&'b self) -> () {
        let child = Child::new(&self);
        self.children.push(child);
    }

    fn do_stuff(&self) -> () {
        self.add_child();
        self.add_child();
    }
}

struct Child<'a> {
    parent: &'a Parent<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Child<'a> {
    fn new(parent: &'a Parent<'a>) -> Child<'a> {
        Child { parent }
    }
}
```

I also came up with some different workarounds, like defining `Vec<Child>` outside the Parent struct, in the main fn, but that doesnt really help me, because I need to use them in Parent later.

Comment: _You don't._ Depending on what the ultimate goal is, then your options may vary. The dead simple solution would be to represent `Parent` and `Child` as a `Node`, and have each of them store `NodeId`s. Then have a collection of `HashMap<NodeId, Node>`. Then you resolve a `Child`s `Parent` by getting the `Parent`s `NodeId` stored in `Child` and looking it up in the `HashMap`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html), **but make sure** you use [`Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html). Because cycles between `Rc`s will never deallocate

Comment: Thats a bummer, though it makes sense. I guess ill just restructure it in a more linear way instead, thanks you !